# dropdown disseappering when moving to it (navigation ie) (pure CSS)

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm working on a menu that works fine in every browser except ie.
a few things are bit weird and done quickly, but it works fine except for ie.
when moving to the bottom bar it drop display back to none before you can reach the bottom bar.
I have both li and ul on :hover with display:block;, but I can't figure out how to fix the problem.

I've put the navigation on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vUxpE/22/

Everything I've tried so far didn't work. I've got no clue why at the moment. Maybe you guys can put a light on it

CSS:

```
#nav {
    height:64px;
    width:100%;
    background:#f0f0f0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #d3d5d2 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f0f0f0), color-stop(100%, #d3d5d2));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #d3d5d2 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #d3d5d2 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0f0f0 0%, #d3d5d2 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0f0f0 0%, #d3d5d2 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#d3d5d2', GradientType=0);
    border:#e2e2e2 1px solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
#nav ul {
    padding:10px;
}
#nav li {
    float:left;
}
#nav a {
    color:#4d4d4d;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:11px;
    line-height:44px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#nav a:hover {
    background:url(../images/navbutton.png);
    color:#fff;
}
#navtest li ul {
    display:none;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
    left:0;
    width:494px;
}
#navtest li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
#navtest li ul:hover {
    display:block;
}
#navtest li ul a {
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:11px;
}
#navtest li ul a:hover {
    background:none;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.subnav {
    background:url(../images/submenu.png) #000;
    height:64px;
    z-index:10;
}
.subnav li {
    float:left;
    margin:15px;
}
.subnav a {
    color:#fff;
    line-height:34px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.subnav a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <ul id="navtest">
        <li> <a href="#">News</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Latest</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Archive</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Tournaments</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>    <a href="#">DSCL</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Starcraft 2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">League of Legends</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Media</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Photo's</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Video's</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Extra</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Partners</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>    <a href="#">DSCL</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="#">Knights</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">About Us</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class="subnav"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi please remove last subnav div

and change #navtest li ul  and try this

```
#navtest li ul {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
display: none;
left: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 67px;
width: 520px;
z-index: 100;
```

}

Comment: This will still result in the dropdown disseappering in internet explorer. also the subnav div is there for the background and for a search box that will come in there, so it's not optional to remove it.